# How do change label text with DomDocument - PHP

Tags: php

I have a label and I have text in this label. I want to change this text. I can only change the title in the current code. How can I change the text according to the title? So the part I want to change is the "texttextedit" part.

```
<?php
$classname = 'Damat Adi';
  $dom = new DOMDocument;
  $dom->loadHTML('<label id="2" style="white-space: pre-wrap; width: 218px; left: 100px; top: 149px; position: absolute; margin-bottom: 0px; z-index: 3; transform: rotate(0deg); font-size: 67px; height: 103px; right: auto; bottom: auto;" title="Damat Adi">texttextedit</label>');
  $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
  $results = $xpath->query("//*[@title='" . $classname . "']");


foreach($results as $anchor) {
    // replacement of those href values
    $anchor->setAttribute('title', 'asd');
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();

?>
```

output:

```
<label id="2" ... title="asd"> texttextedit </label>
```

Comment: is this to be done at runtime on current page or on another page?

Comment: What is the content of the label going to be? In a variable or just a string?

Comment: post will be a variable, that incoming value will be a string value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the node content, set the `textContent` attribute of the node...

```
foreach($results as $anchor) {
    $anchor->textContent = "something new";
}
```